# Create different form and tree in odoo 9

Tags: python, xml, odoo-9

I'm building module odoo. In my module need two form and tree with different field from one class. I had been tried, but doesn't work. This is my code

```
<record id="open_view_client_form_view_2_list_my" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Trial</field>
        <field name="res_model">new.trial</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="domain">[]</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="client_form_view_2,client_form_view_2_tree"/>
        <field name="context">{ 'form_view_ref' : 'client_form_view_2', 'tree_view_ref':'client_form_view_2_tree'}</field>    
        <field name="search_view_id" ref="client_form_view_2_filter"/>
        <field name="help" type="html">
          <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
            Click to add a new project.
          </p>
        </field>
    </record>
```

and errors like this `<field name="view_id" ref="client_form_view_2,client_form_view_2_tree"/>`. How can i solve this?

Comment: In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if that site went down in the future!

Comment: @anothernode I'm sorry from my missing. Thank you for your notice. I had been edited my question.

Comment: No need to apologize. My comment was just intended as a friendly hint. Thanks for editing your question!

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue is that the `view_id` is a Many2one field, meaning that you can only specify one view in the `ref` argument. You should specify the reference for whichever view will be primary (displayed first). In your case, your `view_mode` specifies that the `tree` view will be primary.

```
<field name="view_id" ref="client_form_view_2_tree"/>
```

<sup>It's also best practice to identify the ref by `"module_name.view_name"` although technically there is nothing wrong with the above.</sup>

It does seem like your `context` is properly set up to handle displaying the correct form view. So, I think your code should be good once you update the `view_id`.

---

If that is still not working, then you may need to make use of the `views` argument for the action. See the [Actions Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/actions.html#window-actions-ir-actions-act-window) for more details, but the idea is this:

```
<field name="views">[(id, name), (id, name)]</field>
<!-- This is just an example. You may have to tweak this to work properly -->
<field name="views">[('your_module.tree_view', 'tree'), ('your_module.form_view', 'form')]</field>
```

> A list of (view_id, view_type) pairs. The second element of each pair
>   is the category of the view (tree, form, graph, ...) and the first is
>   an optional database id (or False). If no id is provided, the client
>   should fetch the default view of the specified type for the requested
>   model (this is automatically done by fields_view_get()). The first
>   type of the list is the default view type and will be open by default
>   when the action is executed. Each view type should be present at most
>   once in the list

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Work for different tree, but doesn't work to different form. This is my new code  
<field name="view_ids" eval="[(5, 0, 0),
                (0, 0, {'view_mode': 'tree', 'view_id': ref('client_form_view_2_tree')}),
                (0, 0, {'view_mode': 'form', 'view_id': ref('client_form_view_2')})]"/>